# 'then' and 'catch' called one after annother

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

Why 'then' and 'catch' is both called if I add callback function?

```
function sendMail(data, callback) {

    sgMail
        .send(data)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Email sent');
            callback(true);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
            callback(false);
        })
}
```

I'm sorry if its duplicate I just cant find an answer.

Comment: Sounds like `callback` throws?

Comment: call back throws an error?

Comment: Sure sounds like it

Comment: `sendMail` should not take a `callback` argument in the first place. Just `return` a promise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`catch()` will run if code in a previous `then()` throws an error.

Take this example:

```js
const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  resolve({ data: true })
})

promise.then(() => {
    console.log('Email sent');
    throw new Error("throw an error")
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    console.log('Error was thrown in then() clause');
})
```

The promise resolve successfully, `then()` executes until it throws an error, then `catch` is run because an error was thrown.

---

However this example never runs the `catch()` because no error is ever thrown.

```js
    const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve({ data: true })
    })

    promise.then(() => {
        console.log('Email sent');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        console.log('Error was thrown in then() clause');
    })
```

Comment: How to check what kind of error my call back throws? I still don't understand where is the problem, my callback now is just empty function when I try to debug this.

Comment: You have a `console.error(error)` line. What does that print out?

Comment: you was right, dumb mistake in call back function. one variable was null. Thank you JS jedi for quick response.